# Gitlab (7.10.1) sidekiq not starting

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab is not starting anymore.

It was working properly for more then 6 months, but now `service gitlab start` ends with:

> Waited 30s for the processes to write their pids, something probably went wrong.

**sidekiq.log** output is:

```
2016-05-19T11:40:38.267Z 1368 TID-ou6ydr8us ERROR: /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:309:in `rescue in establish_connection'
2016-05-19T11:40:42.432Z 1368 TID-ou6zx78fc ERROR: heartbeat: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
2016-05-19T11:40:47.433Z 1368 TID-ou6zx78fc ERROR: heartbeat: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
2016-05-19T11:40:52.434Z 1368 TID-ou6zx78fc ERROR: heartbeat: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
2016-05-19T11:40:57.435Z 1368 TID-ou6zx78fc ERROR: heartbeat: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

I tried executing `redis-cli -h localhost` and it gave me `localhost:6379>` prompt.

**Update:**

I updated gitlab to 7.11, Gitlab webui is working but still not able to push commites, now `sidekiq.log` is showing below output:

```
bundler: command not found: sidekiq
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Below is my system information:

```
System information
System:         Ubuntu 14.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.9.6
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:3.3.0

GitLab information
Version:        7.11.4
Revision:       b725318
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     postgresql
URL:            http://git.devrepublic.nl
HTTP Clone URL: http://git.devrepublic.nl/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@git.devrepublic.nl:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers: github, bitbucket

GitLab Shell
Version:        2.6.3
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

I spent hours but am unable to find cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all files inside `/home/git/gitlab/`  (except hidden files).

Then I ran `git stash` in above folder, It brought back all files (version 7.11)

Then I followed installation step (after cloning code) shown as on Gitlab website.

Changed url etc in gitlab config files (you can find steps on gitlab website)

It solved my error. Hope this will help others.